# Cakephp Session expiration doesn't work?

Tags: session, cakephp, timeout

I'm pretty new to Cakephp. I'd like my sessions data gets expired in 3 days. However, it seems like the expiration time is just a few hours, as when the user logs in, s/he will be logged out in a few hours.

Here is all the changes I have made in core.php:

I added timeout parameter:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
        'defaults' => 'php',
        'timeout' => 4320   
    ));
```

I checked most of the relevant questions and none of the solutions worked for me:

Changing 'timeout' to 'session.timeout', changing 4320 to '4320' and ,...

Thanks for you help in advance. :)

Comment: Well, just based on the time it keeps the user logged in. After a few hours (not sure how many hours) it logs out the user because cache is expired. I will change the engine to File to see if that is the problem. BTW, is there any way for me to check the expiration time of the cache?

Comment: `I checked most of the relevant questions` <- if you don't link to what you've read and explain or demonstrate what happens when trying the solution - there's no reason to think that any found duplicate isn't applicable to this question. All that said, IMO you're better off implementing remember-me cookies than having overly long session timeouts.

Comment: It seems like I mixed up cache with sessoin. Sorry about that. I just updated my question. Login in my code has nothing to do with cache. It's all implemented using session.

Comment: AD7six: I will increase gc_maxlifetime and see what happens. Thank you all for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for same:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'timeout' => 30, // The session will timeout after 30 minutes of inactivity
    'cookieTimeout' => 1440, // The session cookie will live for at most 24 hours, this does not effect session timeouts
    'checkAgent' => false,
    'autoRegenerate' => true, // causes the session expiration time to reset on each page load
));
```

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470018/cakephp-session-timeout-on-inactivity-only)